# while true ; cat > fifo in bash doesn't preserve EOF

Tags: linux, bash, authentication, eof, fifo

I'd like to get randomly generated `/etc/issue` on server. In order to do that I made `/etc/issue` named pipe and started following script:

```
while true ; do
  mygenerator > /etc/issue
done
```

Unfortunately it causes `getty` to enter infinite loop and it's impossible to log in at all. Changing code to following *"fixes"* issue:

```
while true ; do
  mygenerator > /etc/issue
  sleep 1
done
```

But it also limits speed of log in attempts to 1 per second. I'm not sure if it'd have any real repercussions on system but it sounds like serious anomaly that shouldn't occur in any normal machine.

Why first variant cuses infinite loop? I'm also getting infinite loop if I just try to `cat` `/etc/issue` file

Comment: It causes a loop whenever the generator opens and starts writing to the pipe again before the reader has had a chance to read and close the last data from the previous iteration. Why don't you just find (or kludge) a getty to run a program instead of reading `/etc/issue`

Comment: I've looked at the source code for a couple of versions of Linux `getty`, I can't see any reason why they should get into a loop. `getty` simple reads the file until it gets EOF, which should happen when `mygenerator` finishes.

Comment: Are you sure you have the redirection on the `mygenerator` line, not the `done` line? That would cause an infinite loop.

Comment: If `mygenerator` always stays ahead of `getty`, then `getty` can read for an arbitrarily long amount of time without actually reaching the end of the pipe.

Comment: There's the same issue when I use just `echo aaa > /etc/issue` instead of mygenerator (which is `ponysay` to be precise). However with echo _sometimes_ it doesn't enter loop. Still in most cases it does. Looks just like race condition to me. Yes redirect is on command. I know that if it'd be after whole command it'd cause infinite hangup - then even sleep doesn't help. In my case sleep does help like I said but It sounds like crappy workaround.